# Sinatra, how to get everything despite of request method

Tags: ruby, sinatra

according to http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Request/Instance%20Scope

You have the request scope binding inside:

- get, head, post, put, delete, options, patch, link, and unlink blocks
- before and after filters
- helper methods
- templates/views

is there any shortcut to do everything exactly the same despite of methods?

```
get // do
  # do something
end

post // do
  # do something exactly the same as previous
end

put // do
  # do something exactly the same as previous
end

delete // do
  # do something exactly the same as previous
end

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you right. But I think you will catch multiple http verbs at once, for this you can use [multi route](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/blob/master/lib/sinatra/multi_route.rb)

**Example**

```
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/multi_route"
route :get, :post, '/foo' do
  # "GET" or "POST"
  p request.env["REQUEST_METHOD"]
end

# Or for module-style applications
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::MultiRoute
  route :get, :post, '/foo' do
    # ...
  end
end
```